# Proof of Roth-Bourgain Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, fourier-analysis, additive-combinatorics

The following question is from Tao and Vu's Additive combinatorics, at which I am stuck and would appreciate some help.These questions are from the proof of Proposition 10.32 (page 392):

1. (Page 394) how does the followine equation follow from regularity of $\text{Bohr}(S,\rho)$: $\mathbb{E}_{x\in Z}f(x)1_{\text{Bohr}(S,\rho-\rho_1)}(x) \ge \frac{\delta}{2}\mathbb{P}_Z(\text{Bohr}(S,\rho))$.
   I am assuming this has to do something with definition 4.24 of regular bohr sets, but i don't see how.
2. (page 394) in the last para: how is the "crude" bound obtained from the boundedness of $f$ and regularity of $\text{Bohr}(S,\rho)$ :

$\mathbb{P}_z(\text{Bohr}(S,\rho+\rho_2))-\mathbb{P}_Z(\text{Bohr}(S,\rho))\le \frac{\delta^3}{8}\mathbb{P}_Z(\text{Bohr}(S,\rho-\rho_2))$ and then how does this crude bound allows restriction of $y$ to $\text{Bohr}(S,\rho-\rho_2)$ and how do we use the triangle inequality to obtain $$\mathbb{E}_{y\ \in \text{Bohr}(S,\rho-\rho_2)}F(y) \ge \frac{\delta^3}{8}$$

3. (page 395) should the equation be $1_{\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(r)=1_{y+\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(y+z+r)1_{2\cdot\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(y+z+2r)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(*)\;\;$  instead of $1_{\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(r)-1_{y+\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(y+z+r)1_{2\cdot\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(y+z+2r)$, as in the equation below concerning $\tilde{F}(y)$, the expression $1_{\text{Bohr}(S,\rho_1)}(r)$ has been replaced by the RHS of the $(*)$.

If yes, can you please explain how we obtain the equation $(*)$.

Thanks.

Comment: The write-up of Bourgain's bound in Tao and Vu is a little hard to follow. I gave an alternative presentation, with more details fleshed out, in some lecture notes available on http://thomasbloom.org/teaching/AC2021.pdf (Chapter 2).

Comment: @ThomasBloom Thankyou so much, i will go through it and post doubts if I have any.

Comment: If you find any mistakes or have questions in anything in those lecture notes, it is probably more efficient to email me directly about them (my email address is on the first page of the lecture notes).

Comment: Thank you for the kind and generous reply. I will surely let you know if I find any mistake or have questions/doubt.

Comment: @ThomasBloom. Thankyou once again and can you please check your email, the one on the first page wasn't working it seems.